# Using bindActionCreators and mapDispatchToProps in a React functional component gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In a functional component, I use `bindActionCreators` with `mapDispatchToProps`.
When I try to access this through a `props`, I don't see anything. Below is how I use them.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    const actions = Object.assign({}, saveActions);
    return { actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

In my `return`,

I have

```
return (
   ...
   <SaveModal actions={props.actions} />
   ...
)
```

And when I check `this.props.actions` in `SaveModal`, which is a Class Component, it has undefined.
When I check `props.actions` in the `App`, it is also undefined. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the shape of `safeActions`.

The way you are doing this, every `safeActions.x` becomes a `prop.x`.

Also, note that you could just do

```js
export default connect(null, safeActions)(App);
```

to achieve the exact same result.

And *then* note that we recommend using the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks over using `connect` for function components, as it is a lot easier to deal with.

https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api